# Script to query table's column analysis data

Tags: sql, sql-server

e.g:

```
select * from SomeView where tablename = 'tablename';
```

and expected system'll return this result:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------------------+
| tablename | columnName |   type   | size | minvalue | maxvalue | rows_count | avg_length | last_Analysis_Datetime |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------------------+
| xxxx      | xxxx       | nvarchar |  100 | null     | xxx      |       1000 |          3 | 2020-02-26             |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------------------+
```

#### what I've tried:

I can use `EXEC SP_HELPSTATS` + `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS` to get result, but it's not `table result set` data format.

```
EXEC SP_HELPSTATS 'tablename','ALL'
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS(tablename,'STATISTIC_Name')
```

Comment: Have a look at `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` that should get you started.

Comment: @Keith , yes , but it's important on the other part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below official documentation might help you.

> DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS displays current query optimization statistics for a table or indexed view. The query optimizer uses statistics to estimate the cardinality or number of rows in the query result, which enables the query optimizer to create a high quality query plan. For example, the query optimizer could use cardinality estimates to choose the index seek operator instead of the index scan operator in the query plan, improving query performance by avoiding a resource-intensive index scan.

[DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> B. Returning all statistics properties for a table

Edit: [For further need.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-properties-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: thanks , i upvote it , but i want to query with result set

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-properties-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 here header -> `B. Returning all statistics properties for a table`` @Wei